# Replace text for images jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace plain text for images using jQuery. The text is always between brackets, like so: `{x}` The problem however, is that there are always multiple bracketed letters that I want to turn into images. So `{1}{w}{w}` should become `<img src="1.png"><img src="w.png"><img src="w.png">`

So tl;dr: I need a way to turn this:

```
<div class="manacost">{1}{w}{w}</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div class="manacost"><img src="1.png'><img src="w.png"><img src="w.png"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your life will be easier if you check a templating engine (like mustache or handlebar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `replace` method:

```
"{1}{w}{w}".replace(/\{([0-z]+)\}/g, "<img src='$1.png'>");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/ZCyJr/1/)

**Update**: In case you have multiple `.manacost` containers, try something like:

```
$('.manacost').html(function (index, text) {
    this.innerHTML = text.replace(/\{([0-z]+)\}/g, "<img src='$1.png'>")
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/ZCyJr/2/)

Comment: I like this snippet because of it's simplicity. However, what if I had multiple instances of .manacost? You can see what I mean here: http://magicunited.microdesign.nl/product-category/BNG/

Comment: I've chosen your answer as the correct one because of the shorter, more semantic code. Plus it respects the different instances of .manacost, leaving me with more room to adjust my css. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
var content = $('.manacost').text();
var values = [], re = /{([^}]+)}/g, text;

while(text = re.exec(content)) {
    values.push(text[1]);
}
$('.manacost').text('');
$.each( values, function( k, v ) {
  // I don't know where you want to put
  $('.manacost').append('<img src"'+v+'.png" alt="'+k+'"/>');
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, John. Absolutely brilliant. Thank you very much, sir!